# Mac OS X 10.9 Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to

Tags: php, curl, ssl, apache2, osx-mavericks

I updated my mac OS to OS X 10.9.
`OS X 10.9/Apache 2.2.24/PHP 5.4.17`
Now getting the error (Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to...) when attempting to connect to our remote server via cURL.

```
DEFINE("SSL_CERTTYPE", "PEM");  
DEFINE("SSL_KEYPASS", "xxxxxxxxx");
DEFINE("SSL_CERT", $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/certs/mycert.pem"); 
DEFINE("SSL_KEY", $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/certs/mycert.key");

$options = array
(
    CURLOPT_URL            => $url,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_HEADER         => false,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => false,
    CURLOPT_VERBOSE        => false,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => false,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false, 
    CURLOPT_SSLCERT        => SSL_CERT,
    CURLOPT_SSLKEY         => SSL_KEY,
    CURLOPT_SSLKEYPASSWD   => SSL_KEYPASS,
    CURLOPT_SSLCERTTYPE    => SSL_CERTTYPE,
);
```

I have tried setting the SSLVERSION to both 2 and 3 but I still get the error.

Not sure if this is an Apache or PHP issue.  Any guidance would be greatly appreciated. 
*It's also worth noting this was working on 10.8 prior to the update.

Comment: My workaround was to use brew to install php55 and use the built in web server that comes with it.  I suppose this would also work with php54.

Comment: For other who might come across this, I ended up upgraded the version of php:
    `curl -s http://php-osx.liip.ch/install.sh | bash -s 5.5`
Instructions from this site: [link](http://www.coolestguidesontheplanet.com/upgrade-to-php-5-4-or-5-5-mac-osx-10-8-mountain-lion/)

Answer (score 3):

This actually has to do with curl: http://curl.haxx.se/mail/archive-2013-10/0036.html

Apparently Apple moved from OpenSSL to their own Secure Transport protocol which seems to have broken curl's handling of client-side certificates (if required for the connection). The only workaround I've found so far is to remove the client-side certificate requirement, which unfortunately isn't ideal.

**-- Update --**

It appears as though you should be able to use Keychain Access to get this to work, but I haven't been able to thus far.